# How to Read Append Blobs as DataFrames in Azure DataBricks

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks, azure-data-factory, sparkr

My batch processing pipeline in `Azure` has the following scenario: I am using the `copy activity` in `Azure Data Factory` to unzip thousands of zip files, stored in a `blob storage container`. These `zip` files are stored in a nested folder structure inside the container, e.g.

```
zipContainer/deviceA/component1/20220301.zip
```

The resulting unzipped files will be stored in another container, preserving the hierarchy in the sink's `copy behavior` option, e.g.

```
unzipContainer/deviceA/component1/20220301.zip/measurements_01.csv
```

I enabled the logging of the `copy activity` as:

[image]

And then provided the folder path to store the generated logs (in `txt` format), which have the following structure:

| Timestamp | Level | OperationName | OperationItem | Message |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-03-01 15:14:06.9880973 | Info | FileWrite | "deviceA/component1/2022.zip/measurements_01.csv" | "Complete writing file. File is successfully copied." |

I want to read the content of these logs in an `R` notebook in `Azure DataBricks`, in order to get the complete paths for these `csv` files for processing. The command I used, `read.df` is part of `SparkR` library:

```
Logs <- read.df(log_path, source = "csv", header="true", delimiter=",")
```

The following exception is returned:

```
Exception: Incorrect Blob type, please use the correct Blob type to access a blob on the server. Expected BLOCK_BLOB, actual APPEND_BLOB.
```

The generated logs from the `copy activity` is of `append blob` type. `read.df()` can read `block blobs` without any issue.

From the above scenario, how can I read these logs successfully into my `R` session in `DataBricks` ?

Comment: what databricks runtime is used?

Comment: I am using `10.4 LTS (includes Apache Spark 3.2.1, Scala 2.12)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this Microsoft documentation, **Azure Databricks and Hadoop Azure WASB implementations do not support reading append blobs.**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/kb/data-sources/wasb-check-blob-types

And when you try to read this log file of `append blob` type, it gives error saying that `Exception: Incorrect Blob type, please use the correct Blob type to access a blob on the server. Expected BLOCK_BLOB, actual APPEND_BLOB.`

So, you cannot read the log file of append blob type from blob storage account. A solution to this would be to use an azure datalake gen2 storage container for logging. When you run the pipeline using ADLS gen2 for logs, it creates log file of `block blob` type. You can now read this file without any issue from databricks.

Using blob storage for logging:

[image]

Using ADLS gen2 for logging:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As mentionned earlier, WASB does not support append blobs reading.
However **abfss does support it.**

Classic operations such as Dataframe reading still use WASB, however you can force abfss by providing a different path.

On a Python Notebook, you could do the following to read an append blob :

```
df = spark.read.format("csv").load("abfss://<container-name>@<storage-account-name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<path-to-data>")
```

Don't forget to provide access to your storage account first, with a **spark.conf.set**

Hope this help